# tensorflow conv2d unexpected convolution result

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning

I try to migrate a Caffe network and model(weights) to tensorflow.
The original first layer is defined as shown at last, which is a stride one convolution on `1x128x128` gray image with kernel size 5x5, output channel 96.

I converted the weights from `caffemodel` file to `numpy array` following this procedure:

```
net = caffe.Net(model, caffe.TEST);
net.copy_from(weights);
weights = net.params[name][0].data
bais    = net.params[name][1].data
if "fc" in name:
    weights = weights.transpose()#2D
elif "conv" in name:
    weights = weights.transpose(2, 3, 1, 0)
```

`Caffe weights shape:(96, 1, 5, 5),biases shape:(96,)`. After the transpose, new array of `'weights shape:', (5, 5, 1, 96), 'biases shape:', (96,)`, are used to initialize `tensorflow` filter.

`tensorflow` code is as followed:

```
gray = tf.reduce_mean(images, axis=3, keep_dims=True)
self.gray = gray
conv1 = self._conv_layer(gray, name='conv1')

def _conv_layer(self, input_, output_dim=96,
           k_h=3, k_w=3, d_h=1, d_w=1, stddev=0.02,
           name="conv2d"):
    #Note: currently kernel size and input output channel num are decided by loaded filter weights.
    #only strides are decided by calling param.
    with tf.variable_scope(name) as scope:
        filt = self.get_conv_filter(name)
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input_, filt, strides=[1, d_h, d_w, 1], padding='SAME')
        conv_biases = self.get_bias(name)
        return tf.nn.bias_add(conv, conv_biases)

def get_conv_filter(self, name):
        init = tf.constant_initializer(value=weights,
                                       dtype=tf.float32)
        shape = weights.shape
        var = tf.get_variable(name="filter", initializer=init, shape=shape)
        return var
```

I checked the input data of `Caffe` net and `tensorflow`'s tensor `gray`, they are the same numbers with the same 2D layout. `(1,1,128,128)` and `(10, 128, 128, 1)`, `tensorflow` use a batch size of 10.

I also checked the kernel through `Caffe`'s `print(net.blobs['conv1'].data[0,0,...])` and the `numpy array` used to initalize `tensorflow var` with `print(weights[:,:,:,0])`.

the  kernel's first layer screen shot is shown below:
[image: Caffe's kernel]
[image: tensorflow's kernel]

the bias is `-0.65039569` and the upper left corner of the image is:

```
0.30989584  0.30989584  0.29427084  0.21354167  0.16145833
0.30989584  0.30989584  0.29427084  0.21354167  0.16145833
0.28645834  0.28645834  0.27083334  0.19010417  0.09114584
```

However, the two's upper left corner of `conv1`'s first feature map are **different**.(please ignore the irrrelevant 256)

[image: conv results]

Only the leftmost column is consistent. I manually calculated and checked the results, the first and the second value of `Caffe`'s (`-0.71238005 -0.74042225`) are correct according to the definition of convolution, the second value in `tensorflow`'s (`-0.71238005 -0.31195271`) is **incorrect**.

Taking into account the padding, the first value is from 3x3 block of the image, the second should be the 3x4 block.

Since `tensorflow` has the correct first value, computed from the 3x3 block of image corner, I assume the kernel layout and image layout and 'SAME' padding are correct. I thought it was a problem with stride that caused the incorrect second value, but the stride must be one, otherwise `tensorflow`'s `conv1` feature map's size won't be `(10, 128, 128, 96)`.

Caffe's convolution layer def:

```
  input_param { 
    shape: { 
        dim: 10
        dim: 1 
        dim: 128 
        dim: 128 
    } 
  }
  transform_param {
    crop_size: 128
    mirror: false
  }
}
layer{
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
    pad: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.1
    }
  }
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
}
```

UPDATE:

Another contrived experiment(see code bolow) shows the `tensorflow` implementation is able to compute the correct second value. However, the error remains in the above situation. What is it that caused the error in the converted version?

```
input = np.random.rand(100,100)
input = input.reshape([1,100,100,1])
k = np.random.rand(5,5)
k = k.reshape([5,5,1,1])
input_tf = tf.constant(input,dtype=tf.float32)
init = tf.constant_initializer(value=k,
                                       dtype=tf.float32)
filter = tf.get_variable(name="filter", initializer=init, shape=k.shape)
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input_tf, filter, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
```

Comment: is this on CPU?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov caffe is on CPU or gpu, tf is on gpu. But the results are the same.

Comment: what about tensorflow on CPU? There's more variability/complexity in GPU implementation

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov just tried it. still the same.

Comment: tf is 12.0.0rc1

Comment: hm, I wonder if it's a subtle difference in implementations of padding

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Oh however tensorflow's doc API and the first correct value indicate the 2 zero padding in left and upper corner (and maybe right and below). Any possible omission  in my understand?

Comment: It's a bit hard to debug this with arbitrary numbers and a large kernel size.  You could try running the same experiment with 3x3 kernel of all ones in both tf and caffe on an image of also all ones (or all of 0.5 something ez to compute).  The above tf code is incomplete whereas the code below contains shape information and other details.  It seems like it might be missing detail from the above code.